# How do I add click events to dynamically added elements in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add `click` events do dynamically created elements. How do I do that using JQuery?

```
$(function() {
   $('.class').after('<a href="#" onclick="displayHideBox('1'); return false;">Text</a>');
});
```

Comment: Want to make work what exactly? What is your code doing and what do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i make work onclick in jquery?

the question I think you're asking is "how do i add click events to dynamically added elements", right?

lets say your markup is like this:

```
<div id="someContainer">
    <p class="class">asdasd</p>
    <a href="#" class="newLink">Text</a>
</div>
```

if so, you can use `.on()` like this:

```
$("#someContainer").on('click','a.newLink', function() {
    displayHideBox('1');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try that:

```
$(function() {
   $('.class').each(function(){
    // construct link-OBJECT! here
    var link = $('<a />').attr('href', '#').click(function(){ displayHideBox('1'); }).text('Text');
    // insert link after ".class"-element
    $(this).after(link);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
$(function(){
    $('<a />', { href: '#', text: 'Text', click: function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault();
            displayHideBox('1'); 
        }
    }).insertAfter('.class');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PEX7u/1/).