# Cannot add click events to dynamic generated list items by jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

## Jquery Code

this is my jquery function for retrieving list or categories from database which is dynamically genrated by jquery function, I have added click event on each of the generated list items. But its not giving any alert on click.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= base_url('assets/js/jquery.js'); ?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= base_url('assets/js/jquery.min.js'); ?>"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

            getlevel1category();


            $('#cat').click(function () {
                alert();
            });

            function getlevel1category () {
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "HomeController/getLevel1Categories",
                    async: true,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {

                        var html='';
                        var i;
                        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
                        {

                            html +='<li id="cat">'+data[i].Name+'</li>';


                        }
                        $('#level1').html(html);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Could not get data');
                    }
                });
            }
}
</script>
```

## Controller

```
<?php

class HomeController extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('HomeModel');
    }

    public function getLevel1Categories()
    {
        $result = $this->HomeModel->getLevel1Categories();


        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
?>
```

## Model function

```
public function getLevel1Categories()
    {
        $this->db->select()
            ->from('category_level1_tbl');
        $query = $this->db->get()->result();
        return $query;
    }
```

## html

```
<div>
    <div>
        <h3>Level 1  Categories</h3>
    </div>
    <div  >
        <ul id="level1">

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"I have added click event on each of the generated list items"* No, you haven't, not in the code above anyway.

Comment: Separately: IDs **must** be unique in the document, you cannot use the same ID (e.g., `cat`) on more than one element.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223446/how-do-i-add-click-events-to-dynamically-added-elements-in-jquery and so many others.

Comment: Try `html +='<li id="cat' + i '">'+data[i].Name+'</li>';` instead of `html +='<li id="cat">'+data[i].Name+'</li>';` And `$('#cat1').click(function () {
                alert();
            });`

Answer (score 0):

First don't use `id` if the elements are multiple as `id` must be unique, use `class` instead and use event delegation like,

```
$('#level1').on('click','.cat',function () {
   alert();
});
```

Comment: We don't need **yet another** answer to this question. Particularly not two full minutes after the question was closed.

Comment: thnks man its work for me